# Elasticsearch enum field

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I have a field that can only have a finite set of values.
Would it not be more efficient (index-wise, and/or storage-wise) to store it as some kind of ENUM?

Is there some such possibility in elasticsearch?

An example would be the names of the states in a state machine.

Comment: Wouldn't an ENUM type require the throwing of an error if the type-constraint was broken by an attempt to enter a value that is not part of the enumerable type?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it would.  When you index full text fields, Elasticsearch also indexes information like the length of the field, and the position and frequency of each term in the field.

These are irrelevant to ENUM values, and can be excluded completely.

In fact, if you *map* your field as `{"index": "not_analyzed"}` then, besides storing the exact value that you provide without trying to analyze it, it also disables storage of the extra info that I mentioned above.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you're saying. However, I wish to reduce the data even further. If the field has one of three possible values, but the values are very long strings, storing them over and over is still wastefull, even if they are not "analyzed".

Furthermore, I'd like to limit the possible values for that field.

Comment: Well yes and no.  First, in the index, each string is only stored once. That's how an inverted index works.  You have "term": [ list of docs which contain the term].  The value will appear repeatedly within the _source field, but that will be compressed automatically, so probably won't have as great an impact as you expect.

Comment: Just to clarify: if you still want to do LONGNAME -> ENUM mapping, you'll have to do that in your application.

Answer (score 2):

In your app use hash map `{ "enumVal1" => 1, "enumVal2" => 2, "enumValX" => 3 }` and then use in ES only the values from hashmap, this can save space.

Comment: where would you configure that exactly? thanks